# How to build Emacs for an embedded ARM Linux system

Tags: linux, install, build

I am trying to build Emacs for an embedded ARM Linux system. Unfortunately, it is proving to be more difficult than I anticipated. I have the device mounted at `/mnt/my_device`. Now I am not sure exactly how to go about building Emacs from source.

I know I can set the prefix of the install via `--prefix=/mnt/my_device/usr/local`. However, beyond that, things get more difficult. How can I `configure` my Emacs build for my ARM system? After configuration, how do I compile Emacs? Using an ARM toolchain in QEMU or something? I know that there are cross-compiler tools that run on x86 systems, but should I use those given that `configure` may get the wrong info if I run it on my x86 system? Also, I need this installation of Emacs to be [quite minimal](https://superuser.com/questions/617468/minimal-emacs24-installation-on-ubuntu), as this *is* an embedded system and there's not a lot of room.

Any tips that would help cohere and streamline this build process would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you compile Emacs on the device itself (or in emulator)? Because if not, then what options other than cross-compiling do you have? `--prefix` isn't a very useful option for you, it just tells the build where to put the binaries. I don't have Emacs sources on this computer, but my first step would be to run `configure --help` and read what options are available. Perhaps, you can set architecture in those options...

Comment: @wvxvw I searched around for such options, but I couldn't find anything that stuck out to me for architectures and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

First: do you need to run Emacs on that system? Emacs can access remote files easily. Typically you just run it on your local machine. If you only ever access the system remotely, it probably doesn't need Emacs. ARM covers a very wide range of system sizes, from appliances with only a few megabytes of memory to equivalents of a 10-year old PC such as the latest Raspberry Pi model.

Second: do you need to compile Emacs yourself? There are plenty of Linux distributions that have ARM binaries and include Emacs. Distributions intended for smaller systems usually don't have it, but see “First” above. On “larger” distributions such as Debian or Arch, just install the package.

If you determine that you do need to compile Emacs, then you have a choice of cross-compiling or not. Emacs is written in C, and C compilers can work in relatively small amounts of memory. For example, you could compile on something like a Pi — but even a slightly aging PC will do it faster. If the device is powerful enough to cross-compile, then you'll probably want to run a distribution that has an Emacs package anyway.

If you do want to cross-compile, you'll need a cross-compiler. This can be a bit painful to set up sometimes. However, the distribution you're running on the device probably already has a cross-compiler setup. This is your most promising route: use whatever toolchain the distribution uses for its own packages.

Regarding Emacs itself, there are a few instructions in the `INSTALL` file. You'll need to pass the `--host` option to `./configure`. The argument depends on the exact platform, depending on whether it has floating point registers and which standard library it runs. It might look something like `arm-linux-gnueabihf` (with GNU libc and Hardware Floating point). Usually the argument is the same name that the toolchain is installed under; for example a compiler for the `arm-linux-gnueabihf` target is typically called `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.

Comment: You should also read [Bug#13479](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13479) before attempting a cross-compile.

Comment: To answer your first question: unfortunately, the device in question does not have networking support so TRAMP is a no-go. To answer your second question: the Linux distro that is installed on the device is Busybox. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, package management is basically non-existent on Busybox. Cross-compilation therefore also looks bleak. Thanks for the other tips, though; I'll try to keep this stuff in mind and see if I can work something out.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks a lot for the link; the info there looks helpful to my situation.

Comment: @npostavs Sorry, I used the term "distro" loosely ;)

Comment: @GDP2 If your device doesn't have a package manager, you may want to install a Linux distribution in a chroot. I've done that on Android, which has a Linux kernel. Debian's debootstrap make that easy. I recommend searching (there's an overview in  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355142/how-to-set-up-busybox-dpkg-android, and I think there are other threads that could help you), and asking for help if necessary, on [unix.se] rather than here. The easiest solution for you is likely not to involve much that's specific to Emacs if anything.

Comment: @Gilles That is a very interesting idea and probably the best one so far. Thanks! I'll look into it.

Comment: @Gilles Hey, thanks a lot for your tip the other day. So I've followed your instructions, plus some other instructions that I found elsewhere, to get `debootstrap` installed on my system and I'm able to install Emacs to my `deboostrap` target folder. Unfortunately, even the `minbase` variant for `deboostrap` is too large for my device. It is 165MiB, even without Emacs. How can I make my `deboostrap` folder smaller, with Emacs included? Specifically, I need it to fit in *no more than* 80 MiB, preferably less.

Comment: @GDP2 Wow, that's really small to install a modern desktop Linux system. I don't know whether debootstrap can be shrunk further than minbase, and even if it can, you'll need to save more. For example Debian includes a lot of documentation in the base packages; negligible by modern HD/SSD standards but significant for you. You could try openwrt, which is bound to be smaller, and there seems to be third-party Emacs packages. I've never used it, so I can't offer concrete advice about it.

Comment: @Gilles Ok, thanks for the suggestions. Yes, this device is quite limited as it's not intended to run something like Linux. I never thought about the space taken by documentation; that's a good thing to look into. Thanks also for pointing me to `openwrt`, I'll take a look at that as well. Regarding 3rd-party Emacsen, the one I've seen so far that *might* be alright is GNU Zile, although its Lisp interpreter seems very rudimentary. Unfortunately, I'd like to run `calc-mode` from GNU Emacs, and I'm not sure if Zile's interpreter is up to the task. Do you have any further advice?

Comment: @GDP2 I'm pretty sure you'll need GNU Emacs for Calc. What I meant that there are third-party packages in openwrt format with GNU Emacs.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. Thanks for clarifying. I'll post my progress here again if I do indeed make any progress.

Answer (score 0):

try chrooting to the root filesystem - assuming it has a build environment... you can then use the arm compiler.... something like:-

```
cd arm/rootfs
sudo su
cp /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static  usr/bin
cp /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

mount /sys ./sys -o bind
mount /proc ./proc -o bind
mount /dev ./dev -o bind

sudo LC_ALL=C chroot . /bin/bash
# we are not in kansas anymore!

root@jw-XPS-13-9370:/# gcc -dumpmachine
aarch64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I gave up on this project long ago as per the above conversations. Hopefully this will help someone else (if anyone else is attempting to do something similar).

Comment: cheers.... i suppose there might be a use for a computer without emacs on it.... but it's not immediately obvious what that might be.... a door stop? :)

Comment: LOL, good one xD